# useState keeps getting cleared while handling promises

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, promise, use-state

The useState of my react app keeps resetting to default value. It resets when my promise function completes. I have observed this while console logging.
The value imageUpload state is meant to be set then sent with axios but, just as it moves to the next promise the state is reset. It happens only with imageupload

Here is a snippet of the useState function:

```
const [values, setValues] = useState({
name: "",
caption: "",
...
imageUpload: "",
})
```

Here is the main code giving issues:

```
const clickSumbit = (event) => {
setValues({...values, error: '', loading: true})

event.preventDefault();
onFileUpload().then( data => {
  setValues({...values, imageUpload: `https://${storageAccountName}.blob.core.windows.net/all/${event.target.files[0].name}`})

  console.log("imageUpload", imageUpload);
}).then( () => {
  axios.post('/.netlify/functions/addData', values)
  .then(data => {
    console.log("Values posted!")
    setValues({
      ...values,
      name: '',
      description: '',
      photo: '',
      error: "",
      loading: false,
      createdProduct: name
    })
  })
  .catch(error => setValues({...values, error: error})
)
  
})



};
```

Here is a snippet of the onFileupload function

```
const onFileUpload = async () => {

const blobsInContainer = await uploadFileToBlob(fileSelected);
return blobInContainer
};
```

This code was made with intention that, until response if gotten on the succesful completion of onFileUpload function, axios post request will then be successful.

This was worse when I tried to make the OnSumbit() a async function. I am new to async and await, is this normal?

Comment: TL/DR, but "value. It resets when my promise function completes." sounds like a common  issue: `values` probably contains outdated information at the time when `setValues` is called. Update your state like this: `setValues((values) => ({ ...values, etc }))`

Answer (score 1):

useState is an asynchronous operation, so your state may not be updated immediately. I suggest to provide a useEffect listen to values change and call the next request. Also, if your new state depends on the old one, you should pass a function like this:

```
onst clickSumbit = (event) => {
  setValues(prevState => { return {...prevState, error: '', loading: true}})
  event.preventDefault();
  onFileUpload().then( data => {
    setValues(prevState => { return {...prevState, imageUpload: `https://${storageAccountName}.blob.core.windows.net/all/${event.target.files[0].name}`})
  }})
};
```

```
useEffect(() => {
  // only call request when imageUpload is available amd first time it receives image 
  if(values.imageUpload && values.loading) {
    axios.post('/.netlify/functions/addData', values)
     .then(data => {
     setValues( prevState => { return {
      ...prevState,
      name: '',
      description: '',
      photo: '',
      error: "",
      loading: false,
      createdProduct: name
    }})
   })
   .catch(error => setValues({...values, error: error})
 }
}, [values])
```

Remember: useEffect will trigger every time values changes. Therefore, you have to be careful to avoid calling unneccessary requests by using loading state for imageUpload only (or one state dedicate to know the status of imageUpload operation)